# Bootstrap multiple images cropper upload problem

Tags: javascript, php, upload, crop

Herewith is a bootstrap code for cropping multiple images in a modal. I can’t figure out how to collect all cropped images and upload them into the images folder. I appreciate any help

index.php: contains the form and the modal

```
<?php
require 'admin/upload.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Crop multiple images with cropper js</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <style>
            .g-height-50 {
                height: 50px;
            }
            .g-width-50 {
                width: 50px !important;
            }
            @media (min-width: 0){
                .g-pa-30 {
                    padding: 2.14286rem !important;
                }
            }
            .g-bg-secondary {
                background-color: #fafafa !important;
            }
            .u-shadow-v18 {
                box-shadow: 0 5px 10px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
            }
            .g-color-gray-dark-v4 {
                color: #777 !important;
            }
            .g-font-size-12 {
                font-size: 0.85714rem !important;
            }
            .media-comment {
                margin-top:20px
            }
            .singleImageCanvasContainer{
                overflow: hidden;
                width: auto;
                height: auto;
                display: inline-block;
                position: relative;
                padding-right: 0px;
                margin-right: 15px;
                border: 2px solid #dfdfdf;
                margin-bottom: 10px;
                padding: 4px;
                border-radius: .25rem;
            }
            .singleImageCanvasContainer .singleImageCanvasCloseBtn{
                position: absolute;
                right: 0;
            }
            .singleImageCanvasContainer .singleImageCanvas{
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                object-fit: cover;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container m-5">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" accept="image/*" multiple />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal" id="cropperModal">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Upload Images</h4>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    </div>
                    <form action="index_template.php" method="POST" id="myform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <input type="hidden" id="post_img_data" name="image_data_url[]">
                        <div class="modal-body p-4">
                            <div class="img-preview"></div>
                            <div id="galleryImages"></div>
                            <div id="cropper">
                                <canvas id="cropperImg" width="0" height="0"></canvas>
                                <button type="button" class="cropImageBtn btn btn-danger" style="display:none;" id="cropImageBtn">Crop</button>
                            </div>
                            <div id="imageValidate" class="text-danger"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ">Upload</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <?php
                    print_r($_FILES['image_data_url']);
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropperjs/1.5.5/cropper.min.js" integrity="sha512-E4KfIuQAc9ZX6zW1IUJROqxrBqJXPuEcDKP6XesMdu2OV4LW7pj8+gkkyx2y646xEV7yxocPbaTtk2LQIJewXw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropperjs/1.5.5/cropper.min.css" integrity="sha512-Aix44jXZerxlqPbbSLJ03lEsUch9H/CmnNfWxShD6vJBbboR+rPdDXmKN+/QjISWT80D4wMjtM4Kx7+xkLVywQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("body").on("change", "#file", function (e) {
                    $('.singleImageCanvasContainer').remove();
                    $('#post_img_data').val('');
                });
            })
        </script>
        <script>
            var c;
            var galleryImagesContainer = document.getElementById('galleryImages');
            var imageCropFileInput = document.getElementById('file');
            var cropperImageInitCanvas = document.getElementById('cropperImg');
            var cropImageButton = document.getElementById('cropImageBtn');
            function imagesPreview(input) {
                var cropper;
                var img = [];
                if (input.files.length) {
                    var i = 0;
                    var index = 0;
                    for (let singleFile of input.files) {
                        var reader = new FileReader();
                        reader.onload = function (event) {
                            var blobUrl = event.target.result;
                            img.push(new Image());
                            img[i].onload = function (e) {
                                var singleCanvasImageContainer = document.createElement('div');
                                singleCanvasImageContainer.id = 'singleImageCanvasContainer' + index;
                                singleCanvasImageContainer.className = 'singleImageCanvasContainer';
                                var singleCanvasImageCloseBtn = document.createElement('button');
                                var singleCanvasImageCloseBtnText = document.createTextNode('X');
                                singleCanvasImageCloseBtn.id = 'singleImageCanvasCloseBtn' + index;
                                singleCanvasImageCloseBtn.className = 'singleImageCanvasCloseBtn';
                                singleCanvasImageCloseBtn.classList.add("btn", "btn-sm");
                                singleCanvasImageCloseBtn.onclick = function () {
                                    removeSingleCanvas(this)
                                };
singleCanvasImageCloseBtn.appendChild(singleCanvasImageCloseBtnText);singleCanvasImageContainer.appendChild(singleCanvasImageCloseBtn);
                                var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                                canvas.id = 'imageCanvas' + index;
                                canvas.className = 'imageCanvas singleImageCanvas';
                                canvas.width = e.currentTarget.width;
                                canvas.height = e.currentTarget.height;
                                canvas.onclick = function () {
                                    cropInit(canvas.id);
                                };
                                singleCanvasImageContainer.appendChild(canvas)
                                var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                                ctx.drawImage(e.currentTarget, 0, 0);galleryImagesContainer.appendChild(singleCanvasImageContainer);
                                (document.querySelectorAll('.singleImageCanvas').length == input.files.length) {
                                document.querySelectorAll('.singleImageCanvas')[0].getAttribute('id');
                                urlConversion();
                                index++;
                            };
                            img[i].src = blobUrl;
                            i++;
                        }
                        reader.readAsDataURL(singleFile);
                    }
                }
            }
            imageCropFileInput.addEventListener("change", function (event) {
                $('#cropperModal').modal('show');
                var mediaValidation = validatePostMedia(event.target.files);
                if (!mediaValidation) {
                    var $el = $('#file');
                    $el.wrap('<form>').closest('form').get(0).reset();
                    $el.unwrap();
                    return false;
                }
                $('#mediaPreview').empty();
                $('.singleImageCanvasContainer').remove();
                if (cropperImageInitCanvas.cropper) {
                    cropperImageInitCanvas.cropper.destroy();
                    cropperImageInitCanvas.width = 0;
                    cropperImageInitCanvas.height = 0;
                    cropImageButton.style.display = 'none';
                }
                imagesPreview(event.target);
            });
            // Initialize Cropper
            function cropInit(selector) {
                c = document.getElementById(selector);
                if (cropperImageInitCanvas.cropper) {
                    cropperImageInitCanvas.cropper.destroy();
                }
                var allCloseButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.singleImageCanvasCloseBtn');
                for (let element of allCloseButtons) {
                    element.style.display = 'block';
                }
                c.previousSibling.style.display = 'none';
                // c.id = croppedImg;
                var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
                var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
                var image = cropperImageInitCanvas;
                image.width = c.width;
                image.height = c.height;
                var ctx = image.getContext('2d');
                ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
                cropper = new Cropper(image, {
                    aspectRatio: 3 / 1,
                    viewMode: 4,
                    preview: '.img-preview',
                    crop: function (event) {
                        cropImageButton.style.display = 'block';
                    }
                });
            }
            function image_crop() {
                if (cropperImageInitCanvas.cropper) {
                    var cropcanvas = cropperImageInitCanvas.cropper.getCroppedCanvas({
                        width: 250, height: 250
                    });
                    var ctx = cropcanvas.getContext('2d');
                    var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, cropcanvas.width, cropcanvas.height);
                    c.width = cropcanvas.width;
                    c.height = cropcanvas.height;
                    var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
                    ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
                    cropperImageInitCanvas.cropper.destroy();
                    cropperImageInitCanvas.width = 0;
                    cropperImageInitCanvas.height = 0;
                    cropImageButton.style.display = 'none';
                    var allCloseButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.singleImageCanvasCloseBtn');
                    for (let element of allCloseButtons) {
                        element.style.display = 'block';
                    }
                    urlConversion();
                } else {
                    alert('Please select any Image you want to crop');
                }
            }
            cropImageButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
                image_crop();
            });
            function removeSingleCanvas(selector) {
                selector.parentNode.remove();
                urlConversion();
            }
            function urlConversion() {
                var allImageCanvas = document.querySelectorAll('.singleImageCanvas');
                var convertedUrl = '';
                canvasLength = allImageCanvas.length;
                for (let element of allImageCanvas) {
                    convertedUrl += element.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
                    convertedUrl += 'img_url';
                }
                document.getElementById('post_img_data').value = convertedUrl;
            }
        </script>
        <script>
            function validatePostMedia(files) {
                $('#imageValidate').empty();
                let err = 0;
                let ResponseTxt = '';
                if (files.length > 10) {
                    err += 1;
                    ResponseTxt += '<p> You can select maximum 10 files. </p>';
                }
                $(files).each(function (index, file) {
                    if (file.size > 1048576) {
                        err += 1;
                        ResponseTxt += 'File : ' + file.name + ' is greater than 1MB';
                    }
                });
                if (err > 0) {
                    $('#imageValidate').html(ResponseTxt);
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
        </script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                        $('.upload').click(function () {
                    canvas = cropper.getCroppedCanvas({
                        width: 400,
                        height: 400
                    });
                    canvas.toBlob(function (blob) {
                        url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                        var reader = new FileReader();
                        reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
                        reader.onloadend = function () {
                            var base64data = reader.result;
                            $.ajax({
                                type: 'POST',
                                dataType: "json",
                                url: 'admin/upload.php',
                                data: {crop_image: base64data},
                                success: function (data)
                                {
                                    alert('success upload image');
                                }
                            });
                        };
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

upload.php: herewith I'm trying to collect cropped images for uploading and later I plan to store them in mySQL db

```
<?php
$folderPath = '../images/';
foreach($_POST["image_data_url"]['name'] as $key => $value){
$image_parts = explode(";base64,", $_POST['image_data_url']);
$image_type_aux = explode("image/", $image_parts[0]);  
$image_type = $image_type_aux[1];  
$image_base64 = base64_decode($image_parts[1]);  
$file = $folderPath . `uniqid()` . '.png';  
file_put_contents($file, $image_base64);  
echo json_encode(["image uploaded successfully."]);  
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've succesfully implemented this code with this codepen snnipet https://codepen.io/susantapaul/pen/XYyoeQ

```
      //Manage Cropped Image 
        $base64string =  $_POST['post_img_data'];
        $parts   = explode("data:image/jpeg;base64,", $base64string);               
        $postedImg = array();   
        $i=0;
        foreach ($parts as $key => $value) {
            if ($i > 0){        
                $imageparts   = explode("image/", $parts[0]);
                $imagetype    = $imageparts[1];
                $imagebase64  = base64_decode($parts[$i]);
                $file       =  'img-'. uniqid() . '.jpg';
                file_put_contents($file, $imagebase64);
                $dir = "../your-folder/uploads/";
                // if needed resize_image($file, 1600, 1200);
                copy($file, $dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file);                
                $postedImg[] = $file;
                unlink($file);
            }
        $i++;
    }       
        $numItems = count($postedImg);
        $imagesPosted = implode(',', $postedImg);
```